# How to remove double quotes stored in the database while reading through fgetcsv

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

This is my code. Whenever I execute this, data stores in the database in double quote as a "park avenue".

```
if ($_FILES["csv_file"]["size"] > 0) 
{
    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES["csv_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_product(product_id, product_name, date) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //
    //redirect
    header('Location: http://abcd.adisoftronics.in/index.php/abc/csv_1?success=1');     
    die;
}
```

Comment: use str_replace('"',' ',$data[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace them manualy.

```
 if ($data[0]) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_product(product_id, product_name, date) VALUES
  (
  '".str_replace('"','',addslashes($data[0]))."',
  '".str_replace('"','',addslashes($data[1]))."',
  '".str_replace('"','',addslashes($data[2]))."'
   )
 ");
}
```

If you want to take out more chars, you should check into functiosn for that like htmlspecialchar().

Comment: while applying this code we did't need to apply while condition or add while condition...... please give me full code to implement directly into page..

Comment: That code is directly from you question. just replace that part with the changes I did.